# ExpandableListview set bold and normal text when click menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, expandablelistview

I am working on my expandablelistview menu that when I click on the menu item, I want to set the menu item to bold while set the other menu item to normal textype.

ExpandableListAdapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    private HashMap<String, String> imgnamedata;
    private boolean hasChild = false;
    private int selectedItem;


    public ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild, HashMap<String, String> img_data) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
        this.imgnamedata = img_data;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(
                this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }


    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return childPosition;
    }

    public boolean isHasChild (boolean hasChild) {

        return hasChild;
    }

    public void selectItem(int selectedItem){
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,
                childPosition);
        //final HeaderModel header = (HeaderModel) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, null);
        }
        final TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        //txtListChild.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);


        txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isChildSelectable = true;
                txtListChild.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private boolean isHasChild() {
        return hasChild;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(
                this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        int c_size = getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        // changing the +/- on expanded list view

        // this is the +/- text view that act as image.
       // on expand this change to  - and on close it again change to +

        ImageView txt_plusminus = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.plus_txt);

        if (c_size > 0) {
            txt_plusminus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (isExpanded) {
                txt_plusminus.setImageDrawable(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.downarrow));
            } else {
                txt_plusminus.setImageDrawable(this._context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rightarrow));

            }

        } else {
            txt_plusminus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        // lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);


        // Either you can use this below for setting icon in main menu:

        // adding icon to expandable list view
        ImageView imgListGroup = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ic_txt);

        String icn = this.imgnamedata.get(headerTitle);
        if (icn != null) {

            String uri = "@drawable/" + icn;

            int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
            Drawable res = null;
            try {
                res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (res != null) {
                imgListGroup.setImageDrawable(res);

            } else {
                imgListGroup.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

            }
        } else {
            imgListGroup.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ExpandableListView interface1,if_list,adons_list,ss_list,tool_list;
ImageView close_d;
Toolbar toolbar;
WebView webview;
TextView lblListHeader;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
RelativeLayout drawer_relative, interface1_test;
private boolean isSelected = false;
private boolean isChildSelectable = false;
private String selectedText = null;

private DrawerLayout.DrawerListener mDrawerListener = new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int status) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideArg) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
         // toolbar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
       //  invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        // toolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
       // invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    close_d = findViewById(R.id.close_d);

    drawer_relative = findViewById(R.id.drawer_relative);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerListener);
    interface1 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.interface1);
    if_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.if_list);
    adons_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.adons_list);
    ss_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ss_list);
    tool_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.tool_list);
    lblListHeader = (TextView) findViewById(com.dvinfosys.R.id.lblListHeader);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    isSelected = false;


    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar, // nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
            // accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
            // accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // toolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            // invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // toolbar.setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            // invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    ArrayList dashbord_listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> dashbord_listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> img_data = new HashMap<>();
    dashbord_listDataHeader.add("Dashboard");
    dashbord_listDataChild.put("Dashboard",new ArrayList<String>());
    img_data.put("Dashboard","dashboard");
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, dashbord_listDataHeader,
            dashbord_listDataChild,img_data);
    interface1.setAdapter(listAdapter);


    interface1.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);

            selectedText = "Dashboard";
            TextView dashboard = v.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            dashboard.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    });


    HashMap<String, String> img_data1 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> interface_listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    ArrayList interface_listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> sub_data = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> sub_data1 = new ArrayList<>();
    interface_listDataHeader.add("Contacts");
    interface_listDataHeader.add("Newsletters");
    sub_data.add("Search Contacts");
    sub_data.add("Add Contacts");
    sub_data.add("Import Contacts");
    sub_data1.add("Create Newsletter");
    sub_data1.add("My Newsletters");
    interface_listDataChild.put("Contacts", sub_data);
    interface_listDataChild.put("Newsletters", sub_data1);
    img_data1.put("Contacts","contacts");
    img_data1.put("Newsletters","newsletter");

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter1 = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, interface_listDataHeader,
            interface_listDataChild,img_data1);
    if_list.setAdapter(listAdapter1);

    if_list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);

            return false;
        }
    });

    ArrayList addons_listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, String> img_data2 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> addons_listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> sub_data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    addons_listDataHeader.add("Autoresponder");
    addons_listDataHeader.add("My Campaign");
    addons_listDataHeader.add("Split Tests");
    sub_data2.add("Create Autoresponder");
    sub_data2.add("My Autoresponder");
    addons_listDataChild.put("Autoresponder", sub_data2);
    addons_listDataChild.put("My Campaign",new ArrayList<String>());
    addons_listDataChild.put("Split Tests",new ArrayList<String>());
    img_data2.put("Autoresponder","autoresponder");
    img_data2.put("My Campaign","campaign");
    img_data2.put("Split Tests","splittest");
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter2 = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, addons_listDataHeader,
            addons_listDataChild,img_data2);



    adons_list.setAdapter(listAdapter2);
    adons_list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);

            TextView addon_header = v.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

            if (id == 1) {
                selectedText = "Campaign";
            }
            else if (id == 2) {
                selectedText = "Split Tests";
            }
            addon_header.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on the menu item, example: My Newsletter. The menu item "Dashboard" have a bold so I want to set the "Dashboard" to normal typetext and set the menu item "My Newsletter" to bold typetext. And when I click menu item "Create Newsletter", I want to set the the "My Newsletter" to normal typetext and set the menu item "Create Newsletter" to bold.

On my code, what it will do that it will set the menu item to bold when I click on the menu item but it wont set the other menu item to normal.

Can you please show me an example how I could do that using with my code?

**EDIT: I have tried this:**

```
ss_list.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);

            TextView ss_header = v.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            ss_header.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

            if (id == 0) {
                //do something
            }
            else if (id == 1) {
                 //do something
            }

            ss_header.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    });`
```

Comment: Think about your `private int selectedItem;` in the Adapter class. You need something similar for group. Inside `getGroupView()`, check if the group is selected, then set text to BOLD else NORMAL. Your current approach won't work after ListView scrolled because views will be redrawn according to data in your adapter. In addition, you have 3 ListViews and 3 independent Adapters, so the adapters won't work together. This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008815/uncheck-all-checkedtextviews-in-expandablelistview-group

Answer (score -1):

you can try this for changing the text style

```
button/textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD/NORMAL);
```

and on each button press, set the text as you wish.
I hope it could help

Comment: Thanks, where do I need to put them on?

Comment: try to put this on the "onGroupClick" method on for each button ,this methods tell the app what to do when someone press the button

Comment: I have already done that but it wont set the other menu item to normal. Please check in my question that i have edited it as I have already tried.

Comment: im trying to help..
try this insted the null variable "textview.getTypeface()"

Comment: `TextView addon_header = v.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
                addon_header.getTypeface();
                addon_header.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);` is that correct?

Comment: if so it wont change the other menu item to normal. Both menu items will be bold.

Comment: if it do change it to bold, you can add under these new lines that set the other texts to normal

Comment: put this line at the onGroupClick method on each button
for example you have 4 buttons
when you click on button number 1
inside its onGroupClick method you should set the text to be bold for button 1,
and for the other 3 buttons to normal, do that for each button

Comment: I cant because 3 buttons have the same id. I have added them in the array and call the adapter to add the menu items. I dont know what to do?

Comment: Any idea?????????

Comment: Mate im going to sleep, but i will try to help you when im up, tell me if you made that work

Comment: No sorry it dont work.

Comment: I thought you was going to help me when you get up in the morning as it have been past 2 days now and I have not heard from you???